# Library for reading sensor data on Raspberry pi

Tags: python, c, raspberry-pi, microcontroller

I've been playing around with the GPIO pins on my Raspberry pi recently. While trying out a temperature sensor (the DHT11 specifically) and trying to find some code to get it work, i noticed something that seems kind of weird to me. All the code i found is either using libraries specific to the kind of sensor

Like with this python code:

```
import sys
import Adafruit_DHT

while True:

    humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(11, 4)

    print 'Temp: {0:0.1f} C  Humidity: {1:0.1f} %'.format(temperature, humidity)
```

Or implementing it completely from scratch like this c-code:

```
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#define MAXTIMINGS  85
#define DHTPIN      7
int dht11_dat[5] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

void read_dht11_dat()
{
    uint8_t laststate   = HIGH;
    uint8_t counter     = 0;
    uint8_t j       = 0, i;
    float   f; 

    dht11_dat[0] = dht11_dat[1] = dht11_dat[2] = dht11_dat[3] = dht11_dat[4] = 0;

    pinMode( DHTPIN, OUTPUT );
    digitalWrite( DHTPIN, LOW );
    delay( 18 );
    digitalWrite( DHTPIN, HIGH );
    delayMicroseconds( 40 );
    pinMode( DHTPIN, INPUT );

    for ( i = 0; i < MAXTIMINGS; i++ )
    {
        counter = 0;
        while ( digitalRead( DHTPIN ) == laststate )
        {
            counter++;
            delayMicroseconds( 1 );
            if ( counter == 255 )
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        laststate = digitalRead( DHTPIN );

        if ( counter == 255 )
            break;

        if ( (i >= 4) && (i % 2 == 0) )
        {
            dht11_dat[j / 8] <<= 1;
            if ( counter > 16 )
                dht11_dat[j / 8] |= 1;
            j++;
        }
    }

    if ( (j >= 40) &&
         (dht11_dat[4] == ( (dht11_dat[0] + dht11_dat[1] + dht11_dat[2] + dht11_dat[3]) & 0xFF) ) )
    {
        f = dht11_dat[2] * 9. / 5. + 32;
        printf( "Humidity = %d.%d %% Temperature = %d.%d C (%.1f F)\n",
            dht11_dat[0], dht11_dat[1], dht11_dat[2], dht11_dat[3], f );
    }else  {
        printf( "Data not good, skip\n" );
    }
}

int main( void )
{
    printf( "Raspberry Pi wiringPi DHT11 Temperature test program\n" );

    if ( wiringPiSetup() == -1 )
        exit( 1 );

    while ( 1 )
    {
        read_dht11_dat();
        delay( 1000 ); 
    }

    return(0);
}
```

So i was wondering why there is no c-library that just returns the raw data read from a specific pin for all kind of sensors

Basically taking over this part:

```
void read_dht11_dat()
{
    uint8_t laststate   = HIGH;
    uint8_t counter     = 0;
    uint8_t j       = 0, i;
    float   f; 

    dht11_dat[0] = dht11_dat[1] = dht11_dat[2] = dht11_dat[3] = dht11_dat[4] = 0;

    pinMode( DHTPIN, OUTPUT );
    digitalWrite( DHTPIN, LOW );
    delay( 18 );
    digitalWrite( DHTPIN, HIGH );
    delayMicroseconds( 40 );
    pinMode( DHTPIN, INPUT );

    for ( i = 0; i < MAXTIMINGS; i++ )
    {
        counter = 0;
        while ( digitalRead( DHTPIN ) == laststate )
        {
            counter++;
            delayMicroseconds( 1 );
            if ( counter == 255 )
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        laststate = digitalRead( DHTPIN );

        if ( counter == 255 )
            break;

        if ( (i >= 4) && (i % 2 == 0) )
        {
            dht11_dat[j / 8] <<= 1;
            if ( counter > 16 )
                dht11_dat[j / 8] |= 1;
            j++;
        }
    }

    if ( (j >= 40) &&
         (dht11_dat[4] == ( (dht11_dat[0] + dht11_dat[1] + dht11_dat[2] + dht11_dat[3]) & 0xFF) ) )
    {
        f = dht11_dat[2] * 9. / 5. + 32;
        printf( "Humidity = %d.%d %% Temperature = %d.%d C (%.1f F)\n",
            dht11_dat[0], dht11_dat[1], dht11_dat[2], dht11_dat[3], f );
    }else  {
        printf( "Data not good, skip\n" );
    }
}
```

Why is that ?

Comment: as for me using `digitalRead( DHTPIN );` you already read raw data from a specific pin for all kind of sensors - so there is no need other c-library. But raw data from many sensors are useless for human and they need recalculations. And every sensor may need different recalculations. And this is why you have specialized module in Python.

Comment: Least you could do would be to upvote the reply…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to know that the temperature sensor communicates the data via a single GPIO pin, which can be HIGH or LOW. The temperature data for this sensor consist of 5 bytes each. This 5 bytes will stored in dht11_dat array:

```
dht11_dat[0] = dht11_dat[1] = dht11_dat[2] = dht11_dat[3] = dht11_dat[4] = 0;
```

So 5 x 8 (40) signals must be received until the temperature data is complete.
The bytes are composed of these individual bits here:

```
    if ( (i >= 4) && (i % 2 == 0) )
    {
        dht11_dat[j / 8] <<= 1;
        if ( counter > 16 )
            dht11_dat[j / 8] |= 1;
        j++;
    }
```

The last byte is only a checksum for correct communication and will be checked here:

```
if ( (j >= 40) &&
     (dht11_dat[4] == ( (dht11_dat[0] + dht11_dat[1] + dht11_dat[2] + dht11_dat[3]) & 0xFF) ) )
{
```

The temperature value in Celcius is stored in byte 3 and 4:

```
dht11_dat[2], dht11_dat[3]
```